# Maybe move field inside struct method

Tags: rust

I have the following objects:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar(pub i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    pub bars: Vec<Bar>
}
```

Assuming I am in a context where I own the `Foo`, I can move the field:

```
for x in foo.bars { /* ... */ }
```

or I can just use it by reference

```
for x in &foo.bars { /* ... */ }
```

However, I want to load my `Vec<Bar>` dynamically (e.g., from a database), I might have something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar(pub i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    pub __bars: Option<Vec<Bar>>
}

impl Foo {    
    pub fn bars<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a Vec<Bar> {
        if self.__bars.is_none() {
            // load data here
            self.__bars = Some(Vec::new());
        }        
        self.__bars.as_ref().unwrap()        
    }    
}
```

But now I can't move that field (even when I own the struct). Both

```
for x in *foo.bars() { }
```

and

```
for x in foo.bars() { let y = *x; }
```

give me a `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

I could do something like:

```
impl Foo
    pub fn load_bars(&mut self) {
        if self.__bars.is_none() {
            // load data here
            self.__bars = Some(Vec::new());
        }
    }
}

let foo = Foo { /* ... */ };
foo.load_bars();
for x in foo.__bars.unwrap() { }
```

But that is way less "pleasant". Is there some special reference type I can return from my `bars` function that will let me move it later when I need to (and can)?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some special reference type I can return from my bars function that will let me move it

These two concepts are incompatible. A reference points to a location in memory. When you move a value, you change its location in memory, invalidating any references. Accessing old references leads to memory unsafety, so Rust prevents it.

I'd just create another method that destructures the type:

```
fn bars2(mut self) -> Vec<Bar> {
    self.bars();
    self.bars.expect("Impossible, we just ensured it was there")
}
```

Then you can use this method when you wish to take ownership:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { bars: None };
    for x in foo.bars() {
        // by ref
    }
    for x in foo.bars2() {
        // by value
    }
}
```

In *this* case, this works just the same, as there's only the one field in the struct. Once the value is moved into `bars2` and the vector is moved out of `self`, there's nothing left in the original struct to get!

If you did have multiple values, you could extend the method to return a tuple with each value:

```
fn bars2(mut self) -> (Vec<Bar>, String) {
    self.bars();
    let b = self.bars.expect("Impossible, we just ensured it was there");
    (b, self.owned_name)
}
```

Or if there's lots of other values that you don't care about, you could simply [`take`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) the one value:

```
fn bars2(&mut self) -> Vec<Bar> {
    self.bars();
    self.bars.take().expect("Impossible, we just ensured it was there")
}
```

Note that this only requires `&mut self` and leaves `self.bars` as a `None`. In other cases that don't have an `Option`, `mem::swap` or `mem::replace` can potentially be used.

Additionally:

1. Lifetime elision means you don't need any explicit lifetimes on `fn bars`.
2. It's probably better to return a `&[T]` instead of a `&Vec<T>`, as it hides the internal implementation better.
3. Don't name your struct fields with a leading underscore. A leading underscore indicates to Rust programmers that the value is deliberately unused, but these are very clearly used. Rust isn't C++ where member variables and methods are in the same namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, with your `bars2` example that takes `mut self`, the whole struct is moved and then discarded within the function. What I would like is something like `bars2`, but with only a partial move for the field accessed--

Comment: @kardeiz added examples for more than one field